# First two @Html.TextBox elements not clickable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, z-index, return-value

I have an MVC application I'm rewriting from MVC1 to MVC4.  On the search form, the first two @Html.TextBox() elements aren't clickable.  You can tab to them, but not click.  If you put more textbox elements above them they become clickable, if you change the order only the first two are broken.

here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 <h2>Search</h2>
    @if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
    {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(ViewData["ErrorMessage"].ToString(), new { @style = "color: #FF0000" })
    }
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Criteria</legend>
            @using (@Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <label>Social Security Number:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("SSN", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:100%" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("SSN", "*", new { @style = "color: #FF0000" })

                <label>Date of Birth:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("DOB", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:100%" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("DOB", "*", new { @style = "color: #FF0000" })

                <label>First Name:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("FirstName", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:100%" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "*", new { @style = "color: #FF0000" })

                <label>Last Name:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("LastName", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:100%" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("LastName", "*", new { @style = "color: #FF0000" })

                <p style="text-align:center;">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" style="align-items:center"/>
                </p>

            }
        </fieldset>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
```

Comment: it's actually not on this page.  It has to be in the layout page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were unclosed div elements in the Layout page.  After rewriting the Layout, the application worked fine.